# Count lines in C source code ignoring comments and empty lines

Tags: c, linux, shell, line-count

I want to counting lines without comments.

```
cat `find linux-4.10.2 -name "*.c" -print` | wc -l
```

This counting lines in .c files

```
cpp -fpreprocessed -dD -P fork.c
```

This remove comments

```
grep "^\s*$" fork.c
```

This counting empty lines

How to write the command to count lines of code and empty the lines?

Comment: https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc

Comment: grep -v inverts a search. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' fl;do
#your commands here
echo "total lines= $(wc -l <$fl)"
echo "lines without comments= $(wc -l < <(cpp -fpreprocessed -dD -P $fl))"
#Considering that above cpp will return all the lines without the comments.

#more commands
done< <(find linux-4.10.2 -type f -name "*.c" -print0)
```

PS: We use -print0 in find , to have null as filenames delimiter and ensure that all filenames will be handled correctly by while read loop, no matter if they do contain special chars, spaces, etc

PS2: If you advise how the comment lines look like, we can also remove them with other tools like sed.See this example:

```
$ a=$'code\n/*comment1\ncooment2\ncomment3*/\ncode'

$ echo "$a"
code
/*comment1
cooment2
comment3*/
code

$ wc -l <<<"$a"
5

$ sed  '/\/\*/,/\*\//d' <<<"$a"  #for variables you need <<<, for files just one <
code
code

$ wc -l < <(sed  '/\/\*/,/\*\//d' <<<"$a")
2
```